# How to scroll up to view the output of system command in Vim

Tags: vim, macvim

I really like run some system command in vim  like

```
:!rspec
```

but the annoying thing is I can't scroll up to see the output information

[image]

I'm using Macvim in Mac 10.9, anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You should add macvim tag. This behavior depends mostly on terminal emulator behind your Vim or graphic mode you use. It looks like it's something special for MacVim.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't scroll up in output that comes from an external source.

Messages do have a simple scrolling facility but only for the messages over which Vim has full control. See [`:h messages`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/message.html#messages).

Looking at your screenshot though, I can tell you that you're doing it wrong. Running RSpec through `:!rspec` is inefficient. Vim has an RSpec compiler in its runtime.

```
:compiler rspec
:make
```

Now RSpec output is parsed and filled into your quickfix list for easy navigation.

For even more RSpec power such as asynchronous test runs check out [*dispatch.vim*](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch).